# Gitlab CICD pipeline with `hashicorp/terraform:full` image errors with `terraform: command not found`

Tags: docker, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Gitlab pipeline to deploy AWS infrastructure using Terraform. When I use the `hashicorp/terraform:light` image everything works as expected. However, when I use the `hashicorp/terraform:full`, it cannot find `terraform` apparently.

Below is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have:

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  - export AWS_SECRET_KEY
  - terraform init

stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - validate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - planfile

apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform apply -input=false "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual
```

When using `hashicorp/terraform:light`:

[image]

When using `hashicorp/terraform:full`:

[image]

So with `hashicorp/terraform:full` I get a `command not found` error even though nothhing else changed.

How can I make this work with the `hashicorp/terraform:full` Docker image?

Comment: Those screenshots should really be text otherwise it makes it very hard for people to copy paste things or for people with screenreaders to view the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you changing the path in the image?

In `hashicorp/terraform:full`? The `terraform` binary lives under `/go/bin/` in that image while it's under `/bin/` in the `light` image.

If you don't mess with the path then it should be fine. Alternatively include `/go/bin/` in your path and that should also fix it.

Separately, exporting a variable like that doesn't actually achieve anything.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I added /go/bin/ to my path on the gitlab-ci.yml file and it works now. Thanks for the support!